# Recorrer Arreglo JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

mi problema es el siguiente: tengo un **JSON** que me regresa la [API de Youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource) y al intentar ingresar a alguna propiedad me aparece "undefined"

La API de youtube me regresa lo siguiente:

> ```
> // Parte del JSON retornado por la API:
>  {
>   "items": [
>   {
>    "id": {
>     "videoId": "Mfu9jgj_z18",
>    },
>    "title": "Joey Montana - Hola",
>    "channelTitle": "JoeyMontanaVEVO",
>    "thumbnails": {
>     "default": {
>      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mfu9jgj_z18/default.jpg"
>     }
>    }
>   } ]
>  }
> ```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5FkOZb-0Z48ZTNENEloZDdUZ3M/view?usp=sharing

Y mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
$.each(data.items, function (item) {

//URL del video en youtube
html += '<p><a href="http://youtu.be/' + item.id + '">';
        alert(html)

//Miniatura del video
html += '<img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + item.id +'/default.jpg">';

//Agrega el titulo del video y del canal
html += '<h2>' + item.title + ' ' + item.channelTitle + '</h2></a></p>';
count++;

});
```

Hasta aquí todo funciona perfecto pero cuando doy click en el enlace me envía a la pagina http://youtu.be/undefined

Comment: Hola Axel, te invito a que te des el **[tour]** y revises este enlace **[ask]**

Comment: Hola Axel, te recomiendo agregues directamente el código y el json para que quede plasmada en la pregunta.

Comment: por favor coloca un trozo del codigo Json y el trozo del codigo javascript de esta forma perdurara

Answer (score 3):

Lo logico seria que hicieras un `each` de tu arreglo

```
for(var item in data.items) {
    console.log(item.title); //Aqui puedes ver las propiedades de cada 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La Razón por la que recibe  `undefined` es porque **`intenta acceder a una propiedad de un valor`entero** ,  lo cual es no correcto.

[La Documentación](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function) es clara , el primer parámetro será un valor `entero` y otro será el `objeto` iterado con sus propiedades incluidas.

**Ejemplo**

```js
var array = [{'nombre':'Joel', 'edad':24},{'nombre':'Axel', 'edad':20}];
$.each(array, function(item) {
  console.log(item.nombre);/* Undefined*/
  console.log(item); /* Index del Array*/
});
$.each(array, function(index,item) {
  /* Accediendo a las propiedades del Item (segundo parámetro)
    es la forma correcta*/
   console.log(item.nombre);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Para su ejemplo sería algo así el `each`

```
$.each(data.items, function (index,value) {
    console.log(value.id.videoId);
    console.log(value.snippet.title);
});
```

Comment: SIMPLEMENTE EXCELENTE !!! esta solución me resolvió un problema que estuve todo el dia intentando resolver sin llegar a nada  concreto !!! Gracias !!!

Answer (score 1):

El problema principal es que estas accediendo incorrectamente el **JSON** retornado por la [API de Youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource), lo correcto es `item.id.videoId`.

Tambien puedes reemplazar la variable `count` por la propiedad `length` de `data.items`, es decir `count = data.items.length`

Te dejo un ejemplo de tu código con las correcciones:

```js
// Emular el JSON recibido por la API de Youtube
data = {
 "items": [
 {
  "id": {
   "videoId": "Mfu9jgj_z18",
  },
  "title": "Joey Montana - Hola",
  "channelTitle": "JoeyMontanaVEVO",
  "thumbnails": {
   "default": {
    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mfu9jgj_z18/default.jpg"
   }
  }
 } ]
}

var html="";

$.each(data.items, function (i,item) {

 //URL del video en youtube
 html += '<p><a href="http://youtu.be/' + item.id.videoId + '">';

 //Miniatura del video
 html += '<img src="' + item.thumbnails.default.url+'">';

 //Agrega el titulo del video y del canal
 html += '<h2>' + item.title + ' ' + item.channelTitle + '</h2></a></p>';

});
document.write(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```